# Capture Responce Code using javassist agent

Tags: reflection, javassist

This is the thing i want it to be done by my javassist agent.

```
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

But i am not able to get the HttpServletResponse object by javassist.
Or can it be done using reflection

Comment: Could you add more context on what you try to do? Where do you want to add the code? What have you tried?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter I want to Capture the response Object at runtime using javassist. So that i can fetch the response parameters at runtime. But i am not aware of how to fetch the existing Object of a Class from my javassist agent.

Comment: You cannof fetch properties of a class, rather from an instance. You would need to change the method of the class you want to monitor and fetch the instance on any method call. Have a look at any Javassist tutorial for learning how to do this!

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter I went through the javassist doc.But could not found what i wanted. The main issue is are you telling me to fetch the instance which calls the method? Can  you plz share the link or show a sample code for that..

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter And i tried using Reflection too but its now working as expected.. I can get new Instances but not able to fetch the existing instance.